# Eloquent model->exists inconsistency

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a few models,

`Vehicle`, `VehiclePreparation`, `RepairOrders`

The relationships are

- `Vehicle` has one `VehiclePreparation`
- `Vehicle` has many `RepairOrders`
- `VehiclePreparation` has many `RepairOrders`
- `VehiclePreparation` belongs to `Vehicle`
- `RepairOrders` belongs to `Vehicle`
- `RepairOrders` belongs to `VehiclePreparation`

### VehiclePreparation Model

`VehiclePreparation` has many `RepairOrders`

```
public function repair_orders()
{
    if($this->exists) {
        return $this->hasMany(RepairOrder::class)
                    ->whereDate('repair_orders.created_at', '>=', $this->created_at);
    }

    return $this->hasMany(RepairOrder::class);
}
```

Note: I have pseudo coded the relationship keys here. They do work internally so I'm confident that this isn't my problem.

My issue is this; when I load a view from the `VehiclePreparationController` and step through the code, the `if($this->exists)` condition works great and does exactly what I want. My problem comes in when I try to display this information on the `VehicleController` show method.

### VehicleController

```
public function show(Vehicle $vehicle)
{
    $vehicle->load([
        'vehicle_preparation',
        'vehicle_preparation.repair_orders'
    ]);

    return view('vehicle.show', compact('vehicle'));
}
```

When this code runs, I step through my `VehiclePreparation` model and the `exists` property always returns false. This is showing the incorrect repair orders on my vehicle.show page.

So what I've confirmed is, when I load the model directly, the `exists` property works great, but when I load it via a relationship, it doesn't? I'm stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exists` is a method that returns a boolean.

Please use `$this->exists()` instead of `$this->exists`

Refer [documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_exists)

Comment: Absolutely Correct!!